# "No method available for opening" - trying to authenticate google sheets in R on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, authentication, google-sheets

We have an R script that we are scheduling to run daily with cron, and need to authenticate with Google Sheets.

```
> gs4_auth(path = '/path-to/our-service-account-key.json')

Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=... ... ...'
```

Do we simply need to install one of `www-browser`, `links2`, `elinks`, etc. on our Linux server?

**Edit:** We've installed a few of these tools, and now when we run `gs4_auth` from on the Ubuntu server we get:

```
> gs4_auth(path = 'path-to/our-service-account-key.json')

Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
```

From the Linux server, we still do not know how to authenticate in browser... I thought the point of the service-account key was so that manually authenticating in browser was not needed. There is no prompt to manually authenticate when we run `gs4_auth(path = 'path-to/our-service-account-key.json')` locally in RStudio...

**Edit2:** We've reached a point now where we (a) **CAN** run our R script on the Linux server with `Rscript our_file.R`, **BUT** when we try to schedule it with cron, it still throws an error at the authentication part of the code...

Comment: i think the last thing to resolve is a direct path issue! i.e. script is pointing to relative path to service account JSON, not full path.

Comment: Yeah, I wonder if it's a path issue, where it can't find the auth token? cron runs in the job [owner's home directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/what-is-the-working-directory-when-cron-executes-a-job)

Comment: Yep this was it, confirming that setting a full path resolved the final issue with this.